# Wso2IS 5.3.0 Automated Configuration

Tags: deployment, automation, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to automate my Wso2 5.3.0 configuration so that it is easier to setup a Wso2 instance based on our needs.

Is it possible to configure service providers through some configuration file instead of doing it through the admin panel?

Comment: You can try this - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files

Comment: Can you give more details on the kind of service providers you are trying to configure? Specially which inbound authentication mechanism (SAML/OAuth) and authentication mechanisms (basic authentication/ multi factor etc.)

Comment: Hey sorry for late response. I need to configure the SAML2 Web SSO Configuration. So that when i deploy wso2 i push some configuration files and the wso2 sso is ready to go. Not sure if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the administration SOAP API. You need to call different services depending on the configuration (SAML, OIDC ...).
Unfortunately wso2 does not bundle a cli tool for that. We ended up writing our own command line client for export and import.

Comment: Oh really!! Hmmm i see... seems like this is the [page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Service+Provider+Configurations+used+with+APIs)  i am looking for! Too bad we cant just do it through config files. Thnx !!!

Comment: Are there any resources that you found useful to help me out implement this ?

Comment: An introduction can be found at https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Calling+Admin+Services

Answer (score 0):

Searching around i found the doc page about the service for handling policies. It is called EntitlementPolicyAdminService and the doc page can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Entitlement+with+APIs) .

Still too bad that this is not configurable by a config file or something but at least there is a workable solution.